# How to filter GraphQL on subobject with Symfony and API Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, graphql, api-platform.com

Although an experienced developer, I'm fairly new to Symfony/API Platfrom/GraphQL. My task is simple - add a filter to the `Product` entity that allows to filter out only active products. Bonus points if the filter is set by default - that is, by default only active products are returned, and you need to add a parameter if you wish to see the inactive products. But if that's too hard, simply adding a filter will do.

OK, so in my `Product.php` I have (only relevant parts shown):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\BooleanFilter;

/**
 * @ApiFilter(BooleanFilter::class, properties={"active" : "exact"})
 */
class Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $active;
}
```

Then I try to modify an existing query to filter out only the active products:

```
{
  sellers(id: 5, active: true) {
    edges {
      node {
        categories {
          edges {
            node {
              products (active: true) {
                totalCount
                edges {
                  node {
                    name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Buuuut, I get:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"active\" on field \"products\" of type \"Category\".",
      "category": "graphql",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 39,
          "column": 25
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, if I change it to querying the products directly:

```
{
  products (active: true) {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That works!

So, what's going on? I'd like to make the filter on the original query so it returns all of the other data too, not just plain products. What am I doing wrong? It feels like I'm misunderstanding some fundamental concept.

Comment: error message points to `products` on `Category` type/class - it can be different to `Product`

Comment: @xadm - If you mean that `Category.products` might not be of type `Product` then, no - it is the correct type.

Comment: No, different 'features' on both 'points' - you need a separate 'filtering annotation' on `Category.product` - category resolver needs to know if filtering is possible on that field/relation

Comment: @xadm - Ermm... Sorry, you lost me. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: You need a `products.active` filter on `Category` - see [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#filtering-on-nested-properties)

Comment: @xadm - Hmm... I guess I could do that... or even higher, at the `Sellers` level... but that implies that wherever I choose to filter the products, I need to specify this filter again. Can't it be done once, in one place, so that products can always be filtered by activity, no matter through where I get to them?

Comment: @xadm - Also - is it possible to add a default value to the filter?

Comment: No, you want it to filter relation then it must be defined in `Category` - on relation. Don't know if it would work on deeper relation, it wouldn't be practical, too.

Comment: @xadm - I played some more and things are just... weird. First I tried defining the filter for `categories.products.active` on the `Seller` class. In this case I could write in my GraphQL (`Seller (categories_products_active: true)`). However this just filtered all the sellers that have at least one active product, and then for those sellers it returned ALL the products - both active and inactive alike.

Comment: @xadm - After that I tried to define `products.active` on the `Category` class, like you suggested. Now things got _really_ crazy. In my GraphQL I suddenly could write `products (products_active:true)` which... frankly, I don't know what. Certainly the inactive products were still there. I think it filtered the categories leaving only those that have at least one active product. However why was the filter defined on the `products` this time? I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: IMHO you should use filter on Category level: `categories (products_active:true){ edges...`

Comment: @xadm - Well, weirdly, it didn't allow me to do that. Also, wouldn't that filter the categories, rather than the products? I'm trying to find any hints in the documentation about filtering the child object collections, but there are none...

Comment: maybe  simply initial `categories { edges { node { products (active: true) {...` ? should be possible with Category `products.active` filter

Comment: @xadm - No, that doesn't work. If I add `@ApiFilter(BooleanFilter::class, properties={"products.active" : "exact"})` to the `Category` class, what I get is... I can add `products (products_active: false)`, but it doesn't do anything (at least that  I could see)

Comment: @xadm - Also, I just noticed, that the filters that have been added to `seller` are available to be used on `category`, but they don't seem to have any effect there.

Comment: try `@ApiFilter(BooleanFilter::class, properties={"active" : "exact"})` directly on property/field `products` inside `Category` class instead 'dotted' on class.

Comment: @xadm - Tried it, that doesn't have any effect at all. I don't even get a filter available anywhere. I even updated everything to the latest version right now (there were some suspicious bugs in the previous versions). In fact, I'm beginning to suspect that API Platform doesn't even support filtering subresources. I found one github issue where someone suggested implementing a custom filter with accompanying magic to do something that sounded very much like what I'm trying to achieve (except in REST API, not GraphQL).

Comment: I'm affraid you  have to dig deeper into issues on github (f.e. [this](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2149) ), test [example](https://github.com/jamesisaac/api-platform-nested-filter), debug using [core sources](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/GraphQl/Type/FieldsBuilder.php) or finally open a new issue on github.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was a pernicious bug which has been resolved in the master and 2.4 branches (no release yet).
See https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/2970 for details.